# Why are .DS_Store files being created in directories that have never been viewed in Finder?

Tags: macos, filesystems

All the descriptions of .DS_Store files that I have seen say that .DS_Store files are created by the Finder when a directory is viewed. In recent releases of macOS (I am running macOS 12.4), I have encountered situations where .DS_Store files are created in directories that have never been viewed in Finder.

I discovered this problem when building software projects. Performing a clean build typically starts by deleting the build output file tree, using `rm -rf` or the equivalent. I started getting occasional failures in this step, where the reported error was an attempt to delete a non-empty directory. Examining the directory shows a .DS_Store file.

Looking more closely, the problem was not a failure to delete the .DS_Store file; I could delete it fine from the shell. The alternative explanation is that the .DS_Store file was being recreated after it was deleted. If that happened before the call to delete the directory, the directory deletion would fail.

I was able to test this using shell commands on a file tree containing .DS_Store files, using statements like this:

```
find . -name .DS_Store -print
find . -name .DS_Store -exec rm {} \;
find . -name .DS_Store -print
```

The last statement should print nothing, but typically it printed about half the number of files printed by the first statement. In some cases it printed files that were not printed by the first statement, clearly showing that .DS_Store files are being created.

My theory is that some program is using File System events to monitor the file system for changes and it is doing something that causes .DS_Store files to be created. I wonder whether there are cases where reading file metadata causes a .DS_Store file to be created (as a cache). I suspect a backup program might be triggering this problem, as it monitors the file system for changes and reads lots of file metadata.

My questions are:

- Does anyone know of a macOS API that might create a .DS_Store file?
- Can anyone suggest a way to track down the code that is creating a .DS_Store file?

Just to be clear, I am *not* asking for ways to inhibit creation of .DS_Store files by the Finder and I am *not* asking for ways to hide .DS_Store files. (I know those are popular topics.)

Comment: Have you tried using fs_usage to track down which process is creating these files? Something like `sudo fs_usage | grep DS_Store` should do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

@Sagar, thanks for the suggestion. That helped to confirm an explanation I had already come up with. The answer is that Finder creates .DS_Store files in directories contained within a viewed directory for which the Calculate All Sizes option is enabled, presumably as a cache, and to keep the displayed total size up to date, it recalculates and updates the .DS_Store files in response to FSEvents.